# TensorFlow - Getting the variable scope of a tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

If I have a reference to a tensor, is there a way to determine that tensor's variable scope? The `.name` of the tensor should contain the variable scope name, but manually parsing this seems like a bit of a hacky workaround. Is there a more robust method of finding the variable scope? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name scoping is a useful mean to prefix tensors and operators within the scope with a given name, but it is not unique, and not even necessary. Consider that

```
with tf.variable_scope('foo'):
    x = tf.zeros((), name='bar')
```

and

```
x = tf.zeros((), name='foo/bar')
```

results in `x` having the same name.

Variable scopes can even be concatenated:

```
with tf.variable_scope('foo'):
    with tf.variable_scope('bar'):
        x = tf.zeros((), name='qux')
```

so speaking of "the" variable scope of `x` has even less sense.

Note however that the path-like nature of those names make them suitable for use with `os.path` (even on Windows). For example, to get the "path" part of the tensor name (possibly the "variable scope" you are looking for) you could use

```
os.path.split(x.name)[0]
```

Comment: I see. I was looking for a generic way to get the variable scope of a tensor reference so that I could abitrarily determine which `with variable_scope(..., reuse=True)` to enter into to reuse a *related* variable. Specifically, getting the weights of a contrib layer based on the output tensor of that layer. Using the path like splitting in this case will probably work. Thanks!